# Generate META keywords from html content

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, dynamic

Is there some way of dynamically creating keywords.

I want to select random words on current page, maximum of 20, and add it to my META information.

So when I update the page, keywords are automatically updated etc.

Is this possible??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at this thread, you may want to give up on this after reading. It's not worth the effort.

[How can I automatically generate SEO keywords based on dynamic page contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169008/how-can-i-automatically-generate-seo-keywords-based-on-dynamic-page-contents)

Kris

Comment: And if I create a function that runs through the sites text, checks each and every word, gets the most commonly used, and adds it to the meta info...? Shouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: If you insist to populate keywords meta tag anyway, you can do it this way. But keep in mind that doing it on every request, would be quite resource hungry and would decrese the load speed of pages. Also you would have to consider removing quite common, meaningless words like 'and' 'if' 'otherwise' 'although' etc. etc. Hope you get my point ?

Comment: I understand fully. I'll check for string length greater than 4 or even 5. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Tools and scripts cannot decide what are suitable keywords for your website, you've to do-it-yourself. Pick some of the important keywords which you feel a user will type for searching the content which is available on your website.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET 4.0 you can use the new properties MetaKeywords and MetaDescription:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Adding Page meta tags information
   this.Page.MetaKeywords = “ASP.Net 4.0 SEO Meta Tag”;
   this.Page.MetaDescription = “Serializing and Deserializing Thoughts..”;
}
```

But I don't think that it would make sense to generated random keywords. The search engine would look for keywords anyway. I would add content specific keywords.

Nobody really knows how search engines create their index. If you fake your keywords, they are not used, but I could imagine that real keywords that correspond with the content could rate up a page. At least that's what google is telling us.

Comment: Yeah I have created getters and setters for all my meta info. And I don't want to create random keywords, I want to select keywords that are more used than others. Guess this isn't possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the words that are mostly used within the content? Ithnk that's what a search engine would do anyway and therefore it is useless. You could get useless words like 'the'.